# Nginx Behind Traefik Docker "Primary script unknown"

Tags: docker, nginx

I have this app running on Docker behind a traefik container.
Every time I access a URL from the API an expected response is returned, then an error from Nginx, than an expected, and next time an Nginx error... this loop is forever

This is my URL: http://api.preview-tefm.rtdigital.com.br/v1/me (expected: 401 response)

The error after a expected resposnse: `2021/11/05 14:22:16 [error] 9#9: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.1.0.2, server: api.preview-tefm.rtdigital.com.br, request: "GET /v1/me HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.1.0.3:9000", host: "api.preview-tefm.rtdigital.com.br"`

Nginx Conf file:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    proxy_cache_path        /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m max_size=3000m inactive=600m;
    proxy_temp_path         /var/tmp;
    include                 mime.types;
    default_type            application/octet-stream;
    sendfile                on;
    keepalive_timeout       65;

    gzip                    on;
    gzip_comp_level         6;
    gzip_vary               on;
    gzip_min_length         1000;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers            16 8k;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.preview-tefm.rtdigital.com.br;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/app-error.log debug;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/app-access.log;
        charset utf-8;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/webapp/public;

        location /css/ {
            access_log off;
            expires 1d;
        }

        location /img/ {
            access_log off;
            expires 1d;
        }

        location /js/ {
            access_log off;
            expires 1d;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass app:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            # Hide PHP headers
            fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
            fastcgi_hide_header X-CF-Powered-By;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass            http://app:9000;
            proxy_http_version    1.1;
            proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header      Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header      Host $host;
            proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header      X-NginX-Proxy    true;
            proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
            try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
            gzip_static on;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       80;

        server_name admin.preview-tefm.rtdigital.com.br;

        error_log  /var/log/nginx/admin-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/admin-access.log;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/admin;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html?$query_string;
            gzip_static on;
        }
    }
}
```

docker-compose conf:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
    app:
        container_name: "tefm-app"
        build: "${DOCKER_PHP_BUILD}"
        restart: "no"
        expose:
            - "9000"
        volumes:
            - "./webapp:/usr/share/nginx/html/webapp"
        networks:
            - traefik-network
    nginx:
        container_name: "tef-nginx"
        build: "${DOCKER_NGINX_BUILD}"
        restart: "no"
        tty: true
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.tefm-nginx.entrypoints=web"
            - "traefik.http.routers.tefm-nginx.rule=Host(`admin.preview-tefm.rtdigital.com.br`) || Host(`api.preview-tefm.rtdigital.com.br`)"
        volumes:
            - "./admin/build:/usr/share/nginx/html/admin"
            - "./webapp:/usr/share/nginx/html/webapp"
        depends_on:
            - app
        networks:
            - traefik-network
networks:
    traefik-network:
        external: true
```

Nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx"]

CMD ["-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Your nginx config looks weird. What do you want to achieve using `try_files` and `proxy_pass` together in the same location block? Most likely your second error response comes from that `try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;` when nginx is probing `/index.php` (you don't have an `index.php` in your root webserver directory, do you?) I don't understand your app architecture (you are using nodejs and php together? or php with a static js?) so this dialog could take a long time, i think it is better to move it to some chat :)

Comment: it my first time using nginx, it all new for me :), also i am using Laravel so the index.php is there, this is my files architeture inside webapp folder https://github.com/laravel/laravel... will try some changes based on your comment

Comment: So this is just a lavarel app without any additional components that are using something node.js based (like react, angular, etc.)? Then what does mean that `- "./admin/build:/usr/share/nginx/html/admin"` volume?

Comment: Oh yeah, there is a react app here: http://admin.preview-tefm.rtdigital.com.br/
but this is running fine

Comment: Try to remove everything except `try_files` from your `location / { ... }` block, reduild and check. You are using `/usr/share/nginx/html/webapp/public` as your root, is it correct and the `index.php` controller located there and not in the `/usr/share/nginx/html/webapp`?

Comment: ok will try
and yes double checked my index is placed in /usr/share/nginx/html/webapp/public/index.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238916/discussion-between-ivan-shatsky-and-neto).